# How to define gon variables in the rails view (slim files)?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, slim-lang, gon

I have a number of views where I need to pass ruby/rails arrays to javascript/jquery code in my project. I'm using the gon gem which works fine when I define the gon variables in the controller code, but how can I assign the variable in the view code(slim file)?

For example if we have the following code in the controller:

```
gon.test_var = "hello there"
```

and then try to alert it in my jquery/javascript code as shown below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  alert(gon.test_var);
});
```

It works fine.

How can I achieve the same thing by defining the variable in the view file (I should be able to define gon.test_var in the slim file)?

Edit: Please note that the values we assign to the variable are ruby variables and not static string or number.

Comment: All you're needing to do is define a JS variable from a Ruby instance variable?

Answer (score 0):

Set:

```
- name = 'smth'
= current_gon.gon["name"] = name
```

Get:

`= current_gon.gon["name"]`

Comment: HI @manyaka, StackOverflow doesn't like code-only answers. Because you originally provide no explanation of what this code solves, it was flagged and put on a review queue to see if it should be deleted. Please edit your answer and add a comment so someone doesn't delete it in the future.

Answer (score 0):

The official way is to use the global setting of Gon:

```
- Gon.global.push test_var: your_value
```

and use the global data:

```
gon.global.test_var
```

another way is to pass gon as an instance variable. So in your controller your assign

```
@gon = gon
```

then in your view, you can use

```
- @gon.push test_var: your_value
- @gon.test_var2 = your_value # old syntax
```